# Variable/Dynamic/REGEX Virtualhost in Apache?

Tags: apache, config, virtualhost

Just an off the wall question today. Is it posible to vary DocumentRoot of a virtualhost based on the subdomain requested like so?

```
<VirtualHost *>
   ServerName ^VARIABLE$.example.com
   DocumentRoot ~/Sites/^VARIABLE$
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible:

---

#### Step1: Setting up Wildcard DNS

You have to add an **A** Record that points to your server's IP like that:

```
*.example.com.    IN      A       192.168.1.1
```

#### Step2: Set up apache VirtualHost

```
<VirtualHost *>
        ServerName  www.example.com
        ServerAlias *.example.com

        DirectoryIndex index.html 
        DocumentRoot /home/www/www.example.com/htdocs
    ....
</VirtualHost>
```

Notice the important line: `ServerAlias *.example.com`. This will tell Apache that any host with the .example.com suffix will match this virtual host too.

#### Step3: Setting up Rewrite Rules

You have to add this lines in your `.htaccess` file located in your web root folder (eg. `/home/www/www.example.com/htdocs`):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{http_host} .
RewriteCond %{http_host} !^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^([^.]+)\.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/%1/ [R=301,L,QSA]
```

That way a request for `foo.example.com` will redirect visitors to `example.com/foo` and so on. Good luck.

---

(Reference: http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/358)